area surface (Schwarz paradox)
Are there any good articles or publishing about area surface with polyhedral?
I have to do a project about it for my analysis course at university but for now ive only read Cordoba's work.
I have found some articles about Schwarz paradox but I just wanted to know if there are some other works I could read about the topic
thank you all
